# Weird syntax with double line arrow `((r:T)=>f(r))(g)`?

Tags: scala

The code below prints the area and circumference of a circle, but I have no idea how it is working. I am familiar with the basics used there, such as f”$”, Scanner, nextDouble, but why is it starting with ((r: Double => ?

Could you break it down for me?

```
object Main extends App{
  ((r:Double) => println(f"${r*r*Math.PI}%.9f ${2*r*Math.PI}%.9f"))(new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is some strange syntax example or maybe code golf.  Basically, It's defining a function and calling in one line.

The first part

```
((r:Double) => println(f"${r*r*Math.PI}%.9f ${2*r*Math.PI}%.9f"))
```

defines the function.  The syntax `(args) => body` is a "lambda expression" or "function literal" and is used to define a function.

The second part

```
(new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble)
```

Is just calling the function with an argument.  This is the same as calling any other function or method, just that instead of assigning the function to a name and using that name to call it, it's being called directly on the function itself without giving the function a name.

It might be easier to understand if broken down into and equivalent, more sensible code.

```
object Main extends App{

  def printAreaAndCircumference(r: Double): Unit = {
    println(f"${r*r*Math.PI}%.9f ${2*r*Math.PI}%.9f")
  }

  val radius = new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble
  printAreaAndCircumference(radius)
}
```

Comment: yeah, if I see it as a functional literal, the snippet makes sense. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
((r:Double) => println(f"${r*r*Math.PI}%.9f ${2*r*Math.PI}%.9f"))(new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble)
```

is just a function which can be simplified as below

```
object Main extends App{
  val r: Double = new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble
  println(f"${r*r*Math.PI}%.9f ${2*r*Math.PI}%.9f")
}
```

where `$` is used to replace the variable used inside with the actual value of the variable i.e. `r`. `f` outside the inverted comma tells compiler to format the expression used inside inverted comma, here it is to format it to 9 decimal places of `float` number. And `.nextDouble` converts the value read to `double` value.

for example

```
val r = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()
```

In this `r` is read as `String` value

```
  val r = new Scanner(System.in).nextBigInteger()
```

In this `r` is read as `Integer` value

And lastly,

```
  val test = "breakdown"
  println(s"${test}")
```

this would print `breakdown`, here `s` is used to format `String`.